# XAMPP Apache stopped working on Mac

Tags: php, macos, apache, terminal, xampp

I have XAMPP apache running on my machine and its been working for a while now and all of sudden stopped working. I will also note that MySQL Database is also not working. When I start my services it goes from Stopped to Starting back to Stopped like so:

[image]

[image]

When I goto Application log there are no errors:

[image]

and I have my port set to 8080:

[image]

I opened Terminal and ran this command: `sudo apachectl stop` and it returned this: `launchctl: Error unloading: org.apache.httpd` What am i doing wrong? and how can i get xampp back up and running again?

Answer (score 0):

You may already be using that port by another instance of Apache.

run this:

```
 ps aux | grep apache
```

It will probably output a list of the instances of apache you didn't know you have running. You can `kill` those pids and then start apache again. (Or just restart your computer)

For me this has happened because an instance of apache was blocking the port you are trying to use.

Another fix then might be to use another port